# Is there a Python datatype for unordered sets of sets?

Tags: python, set

I want to store sets `A` and `B`, in a set `C`. 
My condition is that if set `A = {a,b}` and set `B = {b,a}`

Then set `A` is equal to set `B`

Set `C` will then be `= {{a,b}}`

Is there a datatype which supports something like this?

Comment: No, since A and B are equal, they'd hash to the same value, so you couldn't have two of them at once. (I'm referring to hashing frozensets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and that datatype is just `set`. The trick is that the *inside* sets have to be `frozenset`s, the immutable counterpart of `set`, for them to be placed inside another set. You may also want to make the outer `set` a `frozenset`, depending on what you want to do with it; for example, if you want to stick these sets inside more layers of sets indefinitely, it's probably easier to go with frozensets for everything.

```
>>> A = frozenset(['a', 'b'])
>>> B = frozenset(['b', 'a'])
>>> C = {A, B}
>>> C
set([frozenset(['a', 'b'])])
```

Comment: Thanks. I also want to know if there are ordered sets which accept non-unique elements. Something like A = {1, 0, 1} and B = {1,1,0} and I can perform an intersection which would give me {1}?

Comment: @user3927312: That... doesn't really sound like any sort of set, not even a multiset. That sounds like a sequence, and the natural choices to model a sequence would be `list` or `tuple`, but it's not clear what you want intersection to mean.

Comment: So if I have A and B like I mentioned above if I were to do a Union then it would give me {1,1,1} and for intersection it would be {1,0,0}. I need them to preserve the order. I just realised that this is pretty much boolean ands and ors.

Comment: @user3927312: That sounds like you're trying to encode sets as a sequence of present/not-present booleans. You could do that with lists/tuples and a manual intersect/union implementation, or with ints and bitwise and/or, or you could drop that encoding and just use `set`/`frozenset`, or you could do something else. We're getting away from the focus of this question, though. If you have more to ask, post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

The [`frozenset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) type meets your criteria:

```
>>> A = frozenset({"a", "b"})
>>> B = frozenset({"b", "a"})
>>> A == B
True
>>> frozenset({ A, B })
frozenset({frozenset({'b', 'a'})})
```